# Asp.Net Form ... Accessabilty for dropdown elements

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have an asp.net web page and I'm looking at different ways to make a form accessible.

On **Example #1** I have a label that is associated to the drop-down, on **Example #2** I have an Aria-Label tag with a description of the drop-down.

The original design had no labels for the drop-downs, so adding them kind of ruins the look and flow of the form. The drop-downs are used for filtering and are inline across the top of the page. Under the drop-downs are two buttons, one for filtering off of whats in the drop-downs and one to reset the form so it shows all results with no filtering.

My question is ... Is adding an Aria-Label tag acceptable, or is an associated label really required?

**Example #1**

```
asp:Label id="lbProgramName" runat="server" Text="Program Name:" AssociatedControlID="ddlProgramName

asp:DropDownList id="ddlProgramName" runat="server" CssClass="span5"
```

**Example #2**

```
asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProgramName" runat="server" CssClass="span5" aria-label="Program Names"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a visual label (like your asp:Label with the AssociatedControlId attribute), you don't need the aria-label. The aria-label is used only when there is no association between a descriptive text and the control.

Comment: I understand that ... what I want to know is if an Aria-Label is an acceptable replacement for a missing 'associated' label? Sorry if I wasn't clear ... :-)

Comment: Aria labels are only used by screen readers (for now). You still need a label for the non-blind users. A label helps associate what you need to type or what the selection is all about. Some users for instance might not understand what they need to put there without a proper question like : Select a program. Making "Select the program" as a first option with no value is insufficient.

Comment: "Making 'Select the program' as a first option with no value is insufficient."   How so?  Its showing the same information but in a compressed format.

Comment: Yes but an option is not a label. It's not programmatically associated to the control as a description. It's similar to this failure example :http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/F82. You should read this to get a good grasp of what you can do: http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html

Comment: If you make Select the program as the first option with no value, just make sure you add a title attribute to the dropdown list with the actual description of the field.